# For which values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the system has solution? Am I correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Consider this equations system of the form $Ax=b$ where
>
> \begin{align*} A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 3\\  2 & 1 & 0 & \alpha\\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\  0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
>  \ b=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  \beta\\  1\\  0 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}
>
> **1.** For which values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the system has solution?
>
> **2.** For which values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the system has an unique
> solution?
>
> **3.** If the system doesn't have an unique solution, describe all
> the solutions

- What I did for **2** is to calculate:

\begin{align*}
Det(A)=-15+\alpha
\end{align*}
So my answer is that the system of equations has an unique solution $\iff$ $A^{-1}$ exists $\iff$ $\alpha\neq15$

i.e., for $\alpha\neq15$ and $\forall \beta$ the system of equations has an unique solution. *Am I correct?*

- For **3** what I did is this:

\begin{align*}
x_1+2x_2+3x_4&=0\\
2x_1+x_2+\alpha x_4&=\beta\\
x_2+x_3&=1\\
x_3+x_4&=0
\end{align*}

From that, I got that the solutions has this form:

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
x_4
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-2(2x_4+1)\\ 
1+x_4\\ 
-x_4\\ 
x_4
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{with } x_4=\frac{3+\beta}{\alpha-9}
\end{align*}

- **My doubts:**

*a)* Am I correct in **2**?

*b)* In **3**, I got $x_4=\frac{3+\beta}{\alpha-9}$, but what happens if $\alpha=9$? Does that means that with $\alpha=9$ then the system hasn't solution?

*c)* For **1**, how can I determine if the system has solution?

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cramer's theorem the system has one and only one solution if $\det(A)\ne 0$ that is for $a\ne 15$.

If $\alpha=15$ the matrix $A$  has rank 3, while the augmented matrix $A|b$ has rank 4, if $\beta\ne -3$, therefore there are no solutions for [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem#Formal_statement).

If $\alpha=15;\;\beta=-3$ the rank of $A|b$ is 3 and the system has infinite solutions depending on $4-3=1$ parameter.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).(x,y,z)=(-3-15 t,1,-3 t)$$
give the solutions
$$x= -2 - 9 t, y = 1 + 3 t, z = -3t;\quad\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Thanks you very very much! Just one little question, how did you get the condition $\beta \neq -3$? @Raffaele